# Check if GPS is Disabled/Enable Android

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude, android-gps

We want to add feature to our running app on android in this way:
if the GPS of the device (mobile/tablet) is enable, so the user can login to the application and otherwise show the user that should enable the GPS of his/her mobile.

the problem with the code is this:
while the user's device GPS is on, the app is working. but as soon as GPS being turned off, it shows the "force stop" or suddenly quit the app.

I split the code into 2 parts in order to make the code easy to read.

Fisrt Part:

```
public class Gps extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps);
    TextView txtgps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txtgps.setText("if you can see this page, it means your\n phone's gps is on");
}


}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

public static boolean isgpsenabled = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(isgpsenabled){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can work with program", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You cant work until you turn on the gps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    
    Button btngps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btngps.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener(MainActivity.this);
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            
            LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener(MainActivity.this);
            service.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
            
            boolean enabled = service
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (!enabled) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "gps دستگاه را روشن کرده و دوباره تلاش کنید.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gps.class));
            
                
        }
    });
        
    }
```

Second Part:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    
    if(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equals(provider)){

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "zzzzzzzzzzzz", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}}
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
Context ctx;

public MyLocationListener(MainActivity c){
    ctx = c.getApplicationContext();
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MainActivity.isgpsenabled=true;
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    
    if(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equals(provider)){

    Toast.makeText(ctx, "gps turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MainActivity.isgpsenabled=false;

}
    }

}
```

Comment: can you add more details on what does not work - I mean be precise on what error are you getting?

Comment: when user turn off gps , exit from program or force close it

Answer (score 0):

public class GpsChangeReceiver   extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {
      final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
          if (manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
//         Toast.makeText(context, "gps goes on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         else
         {
//           Toast.makeText(context, "gps goes off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.exit(0);
         }
  }
}

in gps class you should add below code
public class Gps extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps);
    TextView txtgps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txtgps.setText("if you can see this page, it means your\n phone's gps is on");


GpsChangeReceiver m_gpsChangeReceiver = new GpsChangeReceiver();
this.registerReceiver(m_gpsChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));


}
```

}

Comment: and add this code to androidmanifest.xml:

<receiver android:name=".GpsChangeReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>